# How to set bootstrap footer to the end of the page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, footer

I try to create a website with [Material Design for Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/). This website should have a footer at the end of the website. But the footer appear at the end of the website but rather in the middle(on big screens).
I think there is some CSS magic necessary. But I don’t know how to use the css magic.
Can someone help me please?

Best regards, Marius

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.10/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.10/js/mdb.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark primary-color">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="card m-5" style="width: 22rem;">
    <div class="view overlay">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/352x150" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum dolor Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. C/O https://placeholder.com/text/lorem-ipsum/
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>

<footer class="page-footer font-small blue pt-4">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">
        <h5 class="text-uppercase">Footer Content</h5>
        <p>Here you can use rows and columns to organize your footer content.</p>
      </div>
      <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
        <h5 class="text-uppercase">Links</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
        <h5 class="text-uppercase">Links</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2018 Copyright:
    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Since you are using Bootstrap, you can use its [position utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/) to fix the footer in the bottom

Comment: But I want the footer at the end of the page- not fixed at the bottom of the actual view, because then the footer overlaps the main content.

Comment: Of course you will be also adding margin/padding to compensate for the footer, so that it does not overlap

Comment: And that was my question. How to use margin/padding to set the footer at the end of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution..

i just remove the height of `header` and `footer` from the 100vh height of `main`.

```
<main style="min-height: calc(100vh - 223px); display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.10/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.10/js/mdb.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark primary-color">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main style="min-height: calc(100vh - 223px); display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
  <div class="card m-5" style="width: 22rem;">
    <div class="view overlay">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/352x150" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum dolor Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. C/O https://placeholder.com/text/lorem-ipsum/
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>

<footer class="page-footer font-small blue pt-4">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">
        <h5 class="text-uppercase">Footer Content</h5>
        <p>Here you can use rows and columns to organize your footer content.</p>
      </div>
      <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
        <h5 class="text-uppercase">Links</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
        <h5 class="text-uppercase">Links</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2018 Copyright:
    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```